# Counting using a multidimension array

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I want to create an multidimensional array that will count.
This is the code I have so far and don't know where to go from here. When I print this out I want it to look like 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,etc.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int car[][] = new int[4][4];

        for(int row = 0; row < car.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < car[1].length; col++){
                System.out.print(car[row][col] + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Comment: Hi! What's last item you expect in the series? In other words, to which value to you wish to count?

Keep in mind your array values haven't been initialized yet. All the values will be zero at this stage.

Answer (score 1):

you're creating empty array so every field has value 0

try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int car[][] = new int[4][4];

        int index = 0;

        for(int row = 0; row < car.length; row++){
            for(int col = 0; col < car[1].length; col++){
                car[row][col] = index++;
                System.out.print(car[row][col] + ",");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the values before printing them

```
    for(int row = 0; row < car.length; row++){
        for(int col = 0; col < car[1].length; col++){
            car[row][col] = row * 4 + col;
            System.out.print(car[row][col] + ",");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

But it's silly and pointless to use a multi-dimensional array like this.In my experience, Multi-dimensional arrays are useful in a much more limited scope than how people play with them when they are learning.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
public static void main(String[] agrs) {


    int car[][] = new int[4][4];
    int i = 0;

    for(int row = 0; row < car.length; row++){

        for(int col = 0; col < car[1].length; col++){
            car[row][col] = i++;                
            System.out.print(car[row][col] + ",");
        }

    }

}
```